# EMQ X delayed message

Tags: emq

I'm looking for a solution to publish messages to a special topic after x seconds in EMQX (formerly EMQTT). I've found EMQ X enterprise edition's feature table which shows `Delay and schedule message delivery` is a feature of enterprise edition not `Broker Edition`. On the other side [there is an official plugin](https://github.com/emqx/emqx-delayed-publish) from EMQX team in GitHub which do exactly what I want, Delayed Publish.

So my question is how much the plugin reliable? If they had planned to add this feature into their enterprise edition, why they should create an open source GitHub project to do exactly the same!

Comment: Based on the answer in this topic `https://github.com/emqx/emqx/issues/2207` it seems the open source version support this feature too.

Answer (score 0):

That feature (and the plugin) is in the open source version. If you got info from anywhere says that it is only supported in the enterprise edition, then it is not true.